# How to show only the "package_name.deb" in an apt-get url?

Tags: linux, unix

I have a list generated from the command:

```
apt-get --print-uris --yes install <package> | grep ^\' | cut -d\' -f2 >package.txt
```

With some output like: `

```
http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/f/fakeroot/libfakeroot_1.22-2ubuntu1_amd64.deb
http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/f/fakeroot/fakeroot_1.22-2ubuntu1_amd64.deb
http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gnupg2/gnupg-l10n_2.2.4-1ubuntu1.2_all.deb
http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gnupg2/gnupg-utils_2.2.4-1ubuntu1.2_amd64.deb
```

Tried using grep but I can only remove the: `http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/`

My main goal is to get only the package.deb names in order so that I can generate an index according to dependency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use one more cut like this:

```
apt-get --print-uris --yes install <package> | grep ^\' | cut -d\' -f2 | rev | cut -d '/' -f 1 | rev > package.txt
```

You will get the last file name in any URL and I thing you are interested in same.

**Console Output**

```
user@domain $ apt-get --print-uris --yes install <package> | grep ^\' | cut -d\' -f2 | rev | cut -d '/' -f 1 | rev > package.txt


libfakeroot_1.22-2ubuntu1_amd64.deb
fakeroot_1.22-2ubuntu1_amd64.deb
gnupg-l10n_2.2.4-1ubuntu1.2_all.deb
gnupg-utils_2.2.4-1ubuntu1.2_amd64.deb

user@domain $
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using AWK

```
apt-get --print-uris --yes install <package> | grep ^\' | cut -d\' -f2 | rev | awk 'BEGIN { FS="/"; } { print $1; }' | rev > package.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use sed "s/.*///g" to remove the leading part.

```
apt-get --print-uris --yes install <package> | grep ^\' | cut -d\' -f2 | sed "/.*\///g" >package.txt
```